# Spring batch skip not working for remote chunking

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch (version 4.2.4.RELEASE) remote chunking for one of our workflow. Below is the class details and bean definition:

```
@Component
public class MasterItemWriter extends ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter<String> {
// setting up the required parameters in before step.
}
```

```
  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public MasterItemWriter masterWriter() {
    return new MasterItemWriter();
  }

  @Bean
  @JobScope
  public Step masterStep(
      HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager,
      HibernatePagingItemReader<String> reader,
      JobRepository jobRepository,
      @Value("#{jobParameters['jobName']}") String jobName,
      @Value("#{jobParameters['tenantId']}") String tenantId,
      @Value("#{jobParameters['batchId']}") String batchId) {
    String stepName = tenantId + jobName + batchId + "-Master";
    //Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> skippableExceptions = new HashMap<>();
    //skippableExceptions.put(Exception.class, true);
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get(stepName)
        .<String, String>chunk(config.getChunkSize(jobName))
        .reader(reader)
        .writer(masterWriter())
        .faultTolerant()
        .skipLimit(2)
        .skip(Exception.class)
//        .skipPolicy(new LimitCheckingItemSkipPolicy(2, skippableExceptions))
        .transactionManager(hibernateTransactionManager)
        .repository(jobRepository)
        .build();
  }
```

Now, consider a list of items, **chunk size = 1 and throttleLimit = 1**:

```
["111-a","222-b","333-c","444-d","555-e","666-f","777-g","888-h","999-i"] // total 10 items
```

Consider the below series of events:

1. Publishes `["111-a"]`. **localState expected: 1 , actual: 0**
2. Publishes `["222-b"]`. **localState expected: 2 , actual: 0**
3. `["111-a"]` fails in the worker and the `successful` member of `ChunkResponse` is set to `false`.
4. Tries to publish `["333-c"]`, but now **expecting (expected - actual) > throttleLimit**. Hence, it gets the response for `["111-a"]`, throws `AsynchronousFailureException` and increments the actual. **localState expected: 2 , actual: 1**
   Since the exception occurred in the writer, the `FaultTolerant` retries `["333-c"]` and this time the writer successfully publishes the item `["333-c"]` as **expecting (expected - actual) > throttleLimit** is **false** this time.

This continues and at the end the job **FAILS** after trying **all the items** even though all the items in the worker fails.
I want the job execution to stop immediately when the skipLimit exceeds. But in this scenario due to the retry mechanism of `FaultTolerant` and the underlying logic in the `getNextResult()` in `ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter` to increment the actual is preventing the skip to occur.

Questions:

1. Is there any other way I can apply a skip logic for this particular scenario of Remote Chunking?
2. How will I know which are the items failed in the worker? The `ChunkResponse` doesn't include the items failed. Do I have to extend ChunkResponse or set the items which failed in the message header?

**Note: The workers are running in different threads.**

The above workflow I understood by debugging, pardon if I've explained anything wrong above.

Appreciate your help, thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Is your issue similar to this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/952? 2. I see no way to signal to the manager which items have failed, the worker result is summarized in a `StepContribution` (which reports only partial metrics like read count, filter count, etc). WTR to `Note: The workers are running in different threads`: How is that possible? There is no local chunking in Spring Batch, only remote chunking. So I guess your workers are in different JVMs? Are you running an embedded broker and using separate threads as workers?

Comment: 1. The issue you've referred above isn't similar to the one I'm facing. I wanted to implement skip logic using ```FaultTolerant```. Incrementing the actual from ```ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.getNextResult()``` is preventing the skip when the ```FaultTolerant``` retries for individual items after a chunk failure.

2. We're using separate DMLC threads as workers which can be present in the same jvm or in a different JVM. TIBCO is the message broker.

Comment: 1. In a chunk-oriented setup, there is typically no fault-tolerance at the manager level, all the manager does is reading items and sending them to workers. I said typically but that does not mean it is not possible (so nothing wrong with what you did). However I'm not sure I fully understand the issue you described, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to see what's happening.

Comment: 2. I see no way to do that with what is currently offered by Spring Batch. Extending `ChunkResponse` is a good idea, but you should update the code at the manager end to interpret this additional info.

Comment: Thank you so much @MahmoudBenHassine for your response. I'll try to post a minimal example if possible.